# Elements not starting in new line despite block value?

Tags: css

I just started with HTML and CSS and am obviously still learning the basics. I am running into an issue I do not understand and hope you can provide me with some insight:

The problem I have is that any element I create in HTML / CSS always are rendered at the top left of the screen, in this example I created 2 s and assigned them a size of 200 x 200 px in CSS, display: block. I specified no other values other than a background color to make them visible.

My expected outcome is that div 1 would be in the top left corner of the screen with div 2 beginning just underneath div 1. However, both occupy t5he same space.

However I understood that a block-level element always starts on a new line. So what am I missing?

I know I can enter a custom position div 2 but I also know that shouldn't be necessary: it should automatically start a new line without any further inputs.

Here's what I have, the most basic experiment:

HTML

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"></div>
</body>
</html>`
```

CSS

```
.container1 {
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}

.container1 {
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: crimson;
}
```

I understand that by default both divs should be assigned the block attribute by default and with that, each block should start in a new line. 
But they do not. Container2 will overlap container1. Why is that?

Comment: Currently, both containers in the CSS have the same name, which is why the second container is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your classname for `container2` in CSS file

```css
.container1 {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container2 {  /* Check name */
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your css  rename second class to container2 this is the issue

```css
.container1 {
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}

.container2 {
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: crimson;
}
```

**